# Zend Framework, phpUnit and Doctrine cause problems

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu, doctrine, phpunit

First some basic info:

- Ubuntu latest version
- Zend Framewrok 1.9.6
- Doctrine 1.2.1
- Php unit latest version

I have been following [this](http://www.zendcasts.com/writing-doctrine-unit-tests-with-zend_test/2009/12/) and [this](http://www.zendcasts.com/introducing-doctrine-1-2-integration/2009/11/)tutorial to set up my zend envrionment with doctrine and phpUnit.

My environment is not an emtpy project since I had done some developments before I 
configured doctrine and phpunit. I have created some db classes in my models/DbTable/ folder.
The problem is that the files in this folder cause a problem by running phpunit.

This is the error I get:

```
    Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class JS_Model_DBTable_Addresses in /var/www/nrka/application/models/DbTable/addresses.php on line 19

Call Stack:
    0.0007      62480   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
    0.1662    4484880   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:52
    0.1663    4485612   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:147
    0.1663    4485860   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:156
    0.1678    4491132   5. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:786
    0.1682    4504132   6. include_once('/var/www/nrka/tests/application/bootstrap.php') /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:117
    0.2773    7249284   7. Doctrine_Cli->run() /var/www/nrka/tests/application/bootstrap.php:33
    0.2773    7249348   8. Doctrine_Cli->_run() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Cli.php:452
    0.2789    7259336   9. Doctrine_Cli->executeTask() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Cli.php:498
    0.2790    7259480  10. Doctrine_Task_BuildAllReload->execute() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Cli.php:516
    0.5301   11487988  11. Doctrine_Task_LoadData->execute() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Task/BuildAllReload.php:56
    0.5312   11488028  12. Doctrine_Core::loadData() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Task/LoadData.php:43
    0.5324   11527112  13. Doctrine_Data->importData() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Core.php:996
    0.5372   11641772  14. Doctrine_Data_Import->doImport() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Data.php:222
    0.5375   11642232  15. Doctrine_Data->purge() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Data/Import.php:115
    0.5375   11642300  16. Doctrine_Core::getLoadedModels() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Data.php:263
    0.5382   11690076  17. Doctrine_Core::filterInvalidModels() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Core.php:716
    0.5544   11710976  18. Doctrine_Core::isValidModelClass() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Core.php:763
    0.5544   11711084  19. class_exists() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Core.php:784
    0.5546   11711456  20. Doctrine_Core::modelsAutoload() /var/www/nrka/library/Doctrine/Core.php:0
```

What I think that is happening is that the autoloaders of zend Framework, Doctrine and PHPunit are disturbing each other but I am not sure about it.

Btw. Line 19 of the above file (addresses.ph) is the last line of that file. I have checked other locations wether it's manually included somewhere else but as far as I can see it isn't

This is how my application.ini looks like:

```
production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0

phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/Amsterdam"

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.layout.layoutpath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
resources.view.basePath = /var/www/nrka/public/
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Doctrine"
autoloaderNamespaces0 = "JS_"

;---------
;databases
;---------
doctrine.dsn = "mysql://root:root@localhost/zcdev"
doctrine.data_fixtures_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/data/fixtures"
doctrine.sql_path           = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/data/sql"
doctrine.migrations_path    = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/migrations"
doctrine.yaml_schema_path   = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/schema.yml"
doctrine.models_path        = APPLICATION_PATH "/models"

resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.db.adapter =  mysqli
resources.db.params.host    = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = root
resources.db.params.dbname = ladosa



[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
doctrine.dsn = "mysql://root:root@localhost/zctest"

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

It might give some extra info.

So I am  curious to know if anyone has a solution for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I temporarily solved the problem by using passthru and therefore running the Doctrine Cli outside the PHP environment.
Probably it is far away from being a good stable solution but until come up with something else, this is how i do it:

```
<?php
...
$tmpDir = realpath(getcwd());
$newDir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../application/scripts/');
chdir($newDir);
passthru('./doctrine build-all-reload -force');
chdir($tmpDir);
```

To explain this: I store the path i am in and then generate the path where my doctrine Cli executeable script is. Then i change to that directory. [passthru](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) executes the build-all-reload command, using the -force because of the "Do you really want to ..." question.
And then i cahnge to the original directory again.

This provides me with a fresh Database containing all my data fixtures. You can start this little code whenever you want.
Combined with the Solution in the [Article Database helper for PHPUnit on CodeUtopia](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/08/27/database-helper-for-phpunit/), this works really nice.